# Creating a row of unequal # of imageviews programmatically?

Tags: java, android

I have no idea how to make this work. Whether to make an custom arrayadapter or something else. It seems really simple to do. For each individual, just specify the number of attributes?

For example, I make a [RecycleView array of pet owners](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OJRHZ.gif). I click on one of these people to see how many pets / children / cars they have has:

[image: This is a mockup of what I'm trying to say.]

So for other people, it may go like...

- Chris has 3 pets, 1 kid, 1 car
- Bobby has 0 pets, 0 kids, 1 car
- Person 3 has 6 pets, 5 kids, 2 cars

Ratings bar is similar to what i am trying to do, but it doesn't work with what i'm asking for because all the number of icons and icons themselves can be different (car brands, pet species, gender of children) i don't see that as a reason to mark it as a duplicate.

Comment: This sounds like a list of lists pattern...

Comment: I second @Chris' comment, but for your case, since each person gets loaded in an activity, which also looks like a scrolling activity. You can make a basic layout containing placeholder views, preferably LinearLayouts with ids. Then in your code, you do something like `for(pet:pets){petLinearLayout.addView(new ImageView(this).setDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.id.pet_drawable));}` where pets in this case is a list or you can use the traditional for loop with the number of pets

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I will have to study list of lists, but LinearLayout w/ some views sounds about right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So your layout file might look like;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/pet_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/kids_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/cars_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

You then populate the items like this;

```
//After retrieving the data for say the person object
if(person.getPets().size()>0)
for(pet:pets){petLinearLayout.addView(new    ImageView(this).setDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.id.pet_drawable));}
//Use similar code for children and cars
```